# Call a unix program from a TCL variable

Tags: shell, tcl

My TCL script puts together a call to a command line tool using TCL variables.
I've tried exec or eval for the command line but nothing worked.

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
set dbg 0
set iso 100
set cmd "gphoto2 --set-config-value /main/imgsettings/iso=${iso}"
if {$dbg} {puts $cmd} else {eval $cmd}
```

Gives :

```
invalid command name "gphoto2"
while executing
"gphoto2 --set-config-value /main/imgsettings/iso=100"
("eval" body line 1)
invoked from within
"eval $cmd"
invoked from within
"if {$dbg} {puts $cmd} else {eval $cmd}"
(file "./canon.tcl" line 22)
```

If tried `{ exec $cmd }` but that did not work either.

```
couldn't execute "gphoto2 --set-config-value /main/imgsettings/iso=100": no such file or directory
while executing
"exec $cmd"
invoked from within
"if {$dbg} {puts $cmd} else {exec $cmd}"
(file "./mofi_canon.tcl" line 22)
```

I tried giving absolute path name `/usr/bin/gphoto2` but again no success.
I guess the problem has to do with the entire command string being one object and the unix execution cannot parse it. But what's the way to give it to the shell properly?

from the linux command line of course the command works fine.

```
@ubuntu:~/TCL$ gphoto2 --summary                                        
Camera summary:                                                                
Manufacturer: Canon Inc.
Model: Canon EOS DIGITAL REBEL XSi
```

This is from a kubuntu 14.04 linux.

```
uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 3 21:30:07 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks & Cheers,
Gert

Comment: what output do you get if you were to execute `which gphoto2`.

Comment: I think you need to separate the `$cmd` string into an array of separate strings, one per argument, and then use `exec`.  The error message indicates it couldn't find a single command called `ghphoto2 --set-config-value …`.  You could use `"sh"` and `"-c"` and the current value of `$cmd` too: `else { exec "sh" "-c" $cmd }` or thereabouts — my Tcl/Tk is rusty at best.

Comment: @Red Cricket: Which gphoto2 gives /usr/bin/gphoto2. /usr/bin is also part of the shell $path. Gert

Answer (score 5):

If you are using tcl 8.5 or higher version, then you can use as follows,

```
exec {*}$cmd
```

Else, use the below code

```
eval exec $cmd
```

Let's consider an example as such

**example.tcl**

```
#usr/bin/tclsh
puts $argc
puts [ lindex $argv 0 ]
puts [ lindex $argv 1 ]
```

**execargs.tcl**

```
#usr/bin/tclsh

#Calling the example.tcl file with the command line args
set cmd "tclsh example.tcl 1 2"

#For Tcl versions less than 8.5, this will work
puts [ eval exec $cmd ] 

#For Tcl 8.5 or higher, this will work
puts [ exec {*}$cmd ]
```

Comment: All Tcl programmers are strongly advised to use `{*}` instead of `eval` if at all possible; it definitely doesn't have nasty landmine surprises in it.

Comment: `eval [linsert $cmd 0 exec]` -- I hate that. Hard to read cmd after argument. Better use `exec {*}$cmd`. But that is still better than `eval exec $cmd` which has some surprises...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used tcl in a long while, but I suspect the problem is you are combining the command into one variable.

Try executing

```
exec gphoto2 --set-config-value /main/imgsettings/iso=100
```

in tclsh. That should work.

If you combine the entire command into one var, you are trying to find an executable of that name.